# using "insert into" in mysql , #1054 - Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, relational-database

```
INSERT INTO `student`(`Name`, `Student_number`, `Class`, `Major`) 
VALUES (Smith,17,1,CS),(Brown,8,2,CS)
```

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Smith' in 'field list'

I am looking from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html but I still got error.

I do not understand what I'm missing.

My student table is

```
 name char(30),
 Student_number int primary key,
 Class int,
 Major char(30)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here `Smith` is a string literal and you need to quote around string literal values like below else your DB engine will consider it as column/field.

```
VALUES ('Smith',17,1,'CS')
```

Your query should look like

```
INSERT INTO `student`(`Name`, `Student_number`, `Class`, `Major`) 
VALUES ('Smith',17,1,'CS'),('Brown',8,2,'CS')
```